# Sharing Authlogic session when Rails site homepage responds to two different URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, session-cookies, authlogic

I have a Rails site where the homepage can be accessed by two different URLs (one is country-specific). Logging in using the primary site works fine, but when I view the country-specific URL of the homepage, authentication is no longer present due to the domain being different than config.action_controller.session[:domain] (used for the other homepage version and the rest of the site). Does anyone have any suggestions about how to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://github.com/nfriedly/Javascript-Flash-Cookies) to share the Authlogic single access token between multiple domains of the same app does the trick on Flash-enabled devices. If anyone has a more universal solution, please let me know. Cheers.